# Why does Jupyter downgrade Tensorflow while installing over Conda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I installed Tensorflow and Jupyter over Conda on my Ubuntu server.

To get Intel's optimized Python distribution, I use intel channel:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-247:~$ conda config --add channels intel
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-247:~$ conda create -n idp intelpython3_core python=3
```

I install Tensorflow first:

```
(idp) ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-247:~$ conda install tensorflow
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/idp:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    backports:         1.0-py35_intel_6   intel [intel]
    backports.weakref: 1.0rc1-py35_0           
    bleach:            1.5.0-py35_intel_0 intel [intel]
    html5lib:          0.9999999-py35_0        
    markdown:          2.6.8-py35_0            
    protobuf:          3.2.0-py35_intel_0 intel [intel]
    tensorflow:        1.2.1-py35_0            
    werkzeug:          0.12.2-py35_0           

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
```

And I install Jupyter next:

```
(idp) ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-247:~$ conda install jupyter
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/idp:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    decorator:          4.0.11-py35_intel_0 intel [intel]
    entrypoints:        0.2.2-py35_intel_2  intel [intel]
    get_terminal_size:  1.0.0-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    ipykernel:          4.5.0-py35_intel_9  intel [intel]
    ipython:            5.3.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    ipython_genutils:   0.2.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    ipywidgets:         6.0.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    jinja2:             2.9.5-py35_intel_3  intel [intel]
    jsonschema:         2.5.1-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    jupyter:            1.0.0-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    jupyter_client:     5.0.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    jupyter_console:    5.1.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    jupyter_core:       4.3.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    libsodium:          1.0.10-intel_6      intel [intel]
    markupsafe:         0.23-py35_intel_6   intel [intel]
    mistune:            0.7.4-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    nbconvert:          5.1.1-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    nbformat:           4.3.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    notebook:           5.0.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    pandocfilters:      1.4.1-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    path.py:            10.1-py35_intel_0   intel [intel]
    pexpect:            4.2.1-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    pickleshare:        0.7.4-py35_intel_1  intel [intel]
    prompt_toolkit:     1.0.14-py35_intel_0 intel [intel]
    ptyprocess:         0.5.1-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    pygments:           2.2.0-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    pyzmq:              16.0.2-py35_intel_2 intel [intel]
    simplegeneric:      0.8.1-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    terminado:          0.6-py35_intel_6    intel [intel]
    testpath:           0.3-py35_intel_0    intel [intel]
    tornado:            4.4.2-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    traitlets:          4.3.2-py35_intel_0  intel [intel]
    wcwidth:            0.1.7-py35_intel_5  intel [intel]
    widgetsnbextension: 2.0.0-py35_0        intel
    zeromq:             4.1.5-intel_0       intel [intel]

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    html5lib:           0.9999999-py35_0          --> 0.999-py35_intel_0 intel [intel]

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    tensorflow:         1.2.1-py35_0              --> 1.1.0-np112py35_0
```

Why does Conda downgrade previously installed Tensorflow package? Is it something to do with `intel` channel?

Comment: Most likely, there is a conflict in the dependencies of the tensorflow package and some other package. Try adding the `-v` or `-vv` flags to the install command to see more output.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with Jupyter. For me, it downgrades tensorflow from 2 to 1. If I upgrade tensorflow, then Jupyter is unusable. I don't know why both projects aren't on the main conda channel

Answer (score 2):

I tried recreating your environment and it worked fine for me. Tensorflow did'nt get downgraded. Probably this issue is resolved in the latest releases.

You can also try installing optimized TensorFlow library from Intel Distribution for Python(IDP) through Anaconda- refer [Intel Optimized TensorFlow* Installation Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-optimized-tensorflow-installation-guide).

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing jupyterlab via:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

as in  the official jupyter [guide](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/jupyter). In my case the installation of jupyter through the command `conda install -c anaconda jupyter` downgraded my tensorflow installation from 2.5 to 2.3 leading to problems with GPU.